# How remove text before patern only on line where the patern is?

Tags: bash, shell

I've got the following  file:

```
$cat file
.
.
.
/image/trafficbulletin/black.jpg
.
.
```

When he finds 'black' he should delete everything else only in that line!
I want the result to be

```
.
.
.
black
.
.
```

I'm using 
`$ grep -o -P '(?<=tin/).*(?=.jpg)' file`
But this delete all the other lines :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep -o` will output only strings matching the pattern.

Try with `sed` using backreference:

```
sed 's/.*\(black\).*/\1/' file
```

**Some variations:**

As pointed out in comments, in your case you can also replace lines matching the pattern with desired string:

```
sed '/black/s/.*/black/' file
```

that is equivalent to:

```
sed 's/.*black.*/black/' file
```

With GNU sed you can also use the `c` command in a one liner:

```
sed '/black/c black' file
```

Comment: +1. On another note, since the search pattern is fixed (not regex), this is equivalent: `sed '/black/s/.*/black/' file`

Comment: Worked out great !